# Unicode error when opening a file in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, unicode

I have been having a horrible time just trying to open a file in python 3 because of the "\U" in the "C:\Users..." microsoft path name. I'm getting the error "SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes..."

I've read the other answers to this problem that offer the following solutions:

1. Double the \ to escape the unicode of the "\U"
2. Use a raw string filename = r"C:\Users.."
3. Switch the \ to /.

Whenever I use option 1 and/or 2 it doubles the "\". So, the filepath is wrong because it reads 'C:\\Users\\..." instead of 'C:\Users\...'

I'm trying to open excel files at work to manipulate data, and so option 3 isn't available to me, as I can't change the filepath.

Can someone explain why the "\" are doubling when I use the escape "\" or a raw string?

I've tried every combination of options and can't seem to get this to work.

Sorry for making a new question to an already answered problem, but I couldn't comment on the other answers, and the accepted answers weren't working for me.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying 1 and 2 together or separately? And have you actually tried 3?

Comment: You aren't actually changing the path when switching from "\" to "/", its even the default format of `pwd` `>>> os.system("pwd")
/Users/omer/Dropbox/school/16_fall`

Comment: I've tried every combination, but to answer your question I've mostly tried them separately. I'll post what the output is from what I am doing so you know what I'm seeing

Comment: 'C:\\Users\David\Desktop\mlb_stats_5AUG2016' returns '\\Users\\David\\Desktop\\mlb_stats_5AUG2016'

Comment: filename = r'C:\Users\David\Desktop\mlb_stats_5AUG2016' returns 'C:\\Users\\David\\Desktop\\mlb_stats_5AUG2016'. And these are the filenames returned in the python conolse that generate a file not found error.

Comment: filename = 'C:\\Users\\David\\Desktop\\mlb_stats_5AUG2016' returns 'C:\\Users\\David\\Desktop\\mlb_stats_5AUG2016'. So, no matter what I do I get the double backslashes when I only want one. And I really don't think I am allowed to change the path name at work because it's a standard across my organization, and I'm sure tons of security and scanning programs run off that pathname. So, changing it really isn't an option for me.

Comment: If you're just entering these at the interactive shelk without a `print`, the output is correct, and the file simply isn't there.

Comment: File not found and Unicode errors are *very* different. For the former, are you missing an extension?

Comment: The doubled slash from options 1 & 2 is not wrong. It's just that you're viewing the `repr` of the string at the interactive console, which shows the escapes you'd need to recreate the string if you were typing it out. Try doing `print(escaped_string)`, you won't see the escapes because `print` is showing you the human friendly version of the string, w/o the escapes.

Comment: Please reduce your original program to the shortest possible complete program that demonstrates your error. Please see [mcve] for more info.

Answer (score 2):

The original answers should work.

**Option 1:**

```
file_path = "c:\\User\\USER\\SOMETHINGELSE"
print(file_path);
```

gives:

```
c:\User\USER\SOMETHINGELSE
```

The slash escapes the character next to it, but doesn't print itself.

**Option 2:**

```
file_path = r"c:\User\USER\SOMETHINGELSE"
print(file_path);
```

gives:

```
c:\User\USER\SOMETHINGELSE
```

The r tells the string that it has to take it as literal and not use any escape characters.

**Option 3:**

OK...So if you really can't use options 1 or 2, you could use:

```
import os

file_path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.sep), 'Users', 'USER', 'SOMETHINGELSE')
print(file_path);
```

In this case 'os.path.abspath(os.sep)' returns the root drive you are currently using. In my case C:\.
'os.path.join' concatenates the strings using the current systems delimiter. On windows this is \.

The result is:

```
C:\Users\USER\SOMETHINGELSE
```

But, that is a strange way of doing things when option 1 or 2 should work fine.
Remember not to use the options together. If you combine options 1 and 2 you will not get the correct result. Use one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string with an escape character in it (`\`) and Python displays it's `repr`esentation, it will appear to be doubled:

```
# in the REPL
path = r'C:\Users\Nick'

path 
# 'C:\\Users\\Nick'

print(path)
# C:\Users\Nick

print(repr(path))
# 'C:\\Users\\Nick'
```

You are likely being confused in the REPL by Python printing the representation of a string rather than what it actually contains.

Note that your choices 1 and 2 are identical:

```
'C:\\Users\\Nick' == r'C:\Users\Nick'
# True
```

Also note that if you enter an invalid escape (e.g. `'\D'`), Python will *silently* correct this for you to `'\\D'`. This will issue [a `DeprecationWarning` in Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#deprecated-python-behavior) and a `SyntaxError` at some point in the future.